# .net 6: can not connect from Vuejs to signalR

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, visual-studio-2022

I see a lot of tutorial and I follow tutorial format, but my project failded.
please see my codes:
in vs code, my vue.js project:

> main.js:
>
> ```
> import VueSignalR from '@latelier/vue-signalr'
> Vue.use(VueSignalR, 'https://localhost:7082/chathub')
> ```
>
> test.vue:
>
> ```
> created () {
>   this.$socket.start({
>     log: true // Logging is optional but very helpful during development
>   })
> }
> ```

in vs 2022: my hub project:

> program.cs:
>
> ```
> using WebApp2;
>
> var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
> builder.Services.AddSignalR();
> var app = builder.Build();
>
> app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
> app.UseRouting();
> app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
> {
>     endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
> });
>
> app.Run();
> ```
>
> hub.cs:
>
> ```
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
>
> namespace WebApp2
> {
>     public class ChatHub : Hub
>     {
>         public Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
>         {
>             return Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

but result:
[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbiuP.png)

Comment: I have a Vue.js v2 SPA working with .NET 6 using SingleR, but I don't use @latelier/vue-signalr: try eliminating that component to get things working. Ie. have fewer components so easier to see what is going on.

Comment: Please enable Cors in your .net web application first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these codes to program.cs:

> ```
> builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
> {
>     options.AddPolicy(name: "MyPolicy",
>                 builder =>
>                 {
>                     builder.WithOrigins(
>                         "http://localhost:8081")
>                             .AllowAnyHeader()
>                             .AllowAnyMethod()
>                             .AllowCredentials();
>                 });
> });
> ```

> And 
> `app.UseCors("MyPolicy");`